# How do I get an enum value from a string?

Tags: java, enums

Say I have an enum which that is:

```
public enum FooBar {
  One, Two, Three
}
```

I would like to get the corresponsing enum value of a string, lets say 'Two', and get FooBar.Two.

How can I do this in Java? `Enum.ValueOf()` does not seem to be related.

Comment: huh... `Foobar.valueOf("Two")` should return `Foobar.Two`...

Comment: @jrummell the title was wrong, sorry

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I have the string 'Two' and I want the value.

To do this you use `valueOf` e.g.

```
MyEnum me = MyEnum.valueOf("Two");
```

or

```
MyEnum me = Enum.valueOf(MyEnum.class, "Two");
```

> Enum.ValueOf() does not seem to be related.

It appears it's exactly what you want.

---

You can use either

```
String s = myEnum.toString();
```

or

```
String s = myEnum.name();
```

You can use `toString()` to turn any object in to a String. (Whether that String makes sense of not depends on the implementation ;)

Comment: this is the opsite of what I need. I have the string 'Two' and I want the value. Sorry the title was wrong, English grammar is not my forte

Comment: I got confused when you said you didn't want valueOf when actually you did. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use a different Enum construction. Something like this (i use it in my code):

```
enum ReportTypeEnum {
    DETAILS(1,"Details"),
    SUMMARY(2,"Summary");

    private final Integer value;
    private final String label;

    private ReportTypeEnum(int value, String label) {
        this.value = value;
        this.label = label;
    }

    public static ReportTypeEnum fromValue(Integer value) {
        for (ReportTypeEnum e : ReportTypeEnum.values()) {
            if (e.getValue().equals(value)) {
                return e;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid Enum value = "+value);
    }


    public String getDisplayName() {
        return label;
    }


    public Integer getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

The `getDisplayName()` will return the String representation of the ENUM.

Comment: Whatever the OP is asking (which is not clear) this seems more complicated than what he needs.

Comment: Most likely. But different perspective. I am all for presenting a different view of the solution. Not after points. Just extra food for thought.

Answer (score 1):

```
Enum.valueOf(FooBar.class, nameOfEnum);
```

Where `nameOfEnum` is the String "One", "Two", etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try following Code:

```
enum FooBar
{
    One,Two,Three;
}
public class EnumByName
{
    public static void main(String stp[])
    {
        String names[] = {"One","Two","Three"};
        for (String name : names)
        {
            FooBar fb = Enum.valueOf(FooBar.class,name);
            System.out.println(fb);
        }

    }
}
```